# I am getting a TLE error while performing cycle detection

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I have written a code to the leetcode problem([courseSchedule](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/)) which basically asks whether a given set of courses can be done given dependencies. my approach is to create a graph and then check for a cycle, however, it's giving a TLE error. Can you help me as to why is the TLE happening or if there's a better approach that I can use ?

```
bool cycle( vector<vector<int>> &adj,int i,vector<bool> vis){
    
    if(vis[i])
        return true;
    
    vis[i]=true;
    
    for(int k=0;k<adj[i].size();k++)
       if(cycle(adj,adj[i][k],vis))
           return true;
    
    return false;
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool canFinish(int numCourses, vector<vector<int>>& prerequisites) {
        
        vector<vector<int>> adj(numCourses);
        
        for(int i=0;i<prerequisites.size();i++)
            adj[prerequisites[i][1]].push_back(prerequisites[i][0]);
        
        vector<bool> vis(numCourses,false);
        
        for(int i=0;i<numCourses;i++)
            if(cycle(adj,i,vis))
                return false;
        
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You say that you have "written a code to the leetcode problem", but *which* problem? Please [edit] your question to include the problem itself. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I included the general problem overview, hoping that would suffice.However, I have edited and added the question as well.

Comment: Withoud reading in depth - You're passing a `vector<bool> vis` by value. This is both incorrect and very inefficient. Add a `&` there.

Comment: @BennyK I have intentionally passed it by value as for every check, I perform the vis should be all false

Comment: I don't know what you hope to achieve by passing it by-value. I stand behind what I said - it is incorrect and inefficient (probably the reason for the TLE).

Comment: @BennyK By passing it by value, I don't have to reinitialize it to all false before I check for the other cycle from next vertex

Comment: Arrr,,, Okay, it **may** be correct. But it still runs extremely inefficiently. The whole point of DFS-like algorithms is NOT to reinitialize `vis`. consider this [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/vvv5nv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your function is correct but so inefficient.

This is because in the `cycle` function performs so many redundant operations i.e check for the same node multiple times.

**Your Code:**

```c
bool cycle( vector<vector<int>> &adj,int i,vector<bool> vis){
    
    if(vis[i])
        return true;
    
    vis[i] = true;
    
    for(int k = 0; k < adj[i].size(); k++)
       
       if(cycle(adj, adj[i][k], vis))
           return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

**Ex:**

```
0 ---> 1 ---> 2 ......... (some more edges)

0 ---> 3 ---> 2 ---> 4 ........ (some more edges)
```

So, for this graph, for the start vertex `0` (with your code) for the `bool` function:

***iteration  - 1:***  you perform the DFS and check for `1` and `2` and
......

***iteration  - 2:***  you perform the DFS and check for `3` and again `2` .....

So, like this, you will be recomputing the same sub-problems. To avoid this you need to put another array just check if a node is already computed.

So I have introduced another vector `var` (initialized to false) which basically sets to true if node is ***visited*** and ***got approved as non-cycle node*** (which doesn't involve in a cycle) .

**Improved Code:**

```c
bool cycle( vector<vector<int>> &adj,int i,vector<bool> vis, vector<bool>& var){
    
    // if i involves in cycle and visited in the current sequence
    if(!var[i] and vis[i])
        return true;
    
    vis[i] = true;
    
    for(int k=0;k<adj[i].size();k++) {
       
       // if adj[i][k] is true i.e doesn't involve in cycle, so no need to check it. If it is false we should check it.
       if(!var[adj[i][k]] and cycle(adj,adj[i][k],vis, var))
           return true;
       else 
        var[adj[i][k]] = true; // else setting true to tell it doesn't involve in cycle
    }

    // setting true to tell it doesn't involve in cycle
    var[i] = true;
    
    return false;
}


class Solution {
public:
    bool canFinish(int numCourses, vector<vector<int>>& prerequisites) {
        
        vector<vector<int>> adj(numCourses);
        
        for(int i=0;i<prerequisites.size();i++)
            adj[prerequisites[i][1]].push_back(prerequisites[i][0]);
        
        vector<bool> vis(numCourses,false);
        vector<bool> var(numCourses,false);
        
        for(int i=0;i<numCourses;i++)
            if(cycle(adj,i,vis, var))
                return false;
        
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Note:**

I just made small changes to make your code overcome TLE without changing the basic logic. But this is still inefficient as your logic needs to pass the vector by value. I suggest you think another way :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I also think `vis` is not passed by reference would be the problem for large size test cases.

This is a similar depth first search graph method, that'd pass through:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

const static struct Solution {
    static bool canFinish(
        const int num_courses,
        const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& prerequisites
    ) {
        GraphType graph = buildCourseGraph(prerequisites, num_courses);
        std::vector<bool> to_take(num_courses, false);
        std::vector<bool> taken(num_courses, false);

        for (SizeType course = 0; course < num_courses; ++course) {
            if (!taken[course] && !validateAcyclic(graph, course, to_take, taken)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

private:
    using GraphType = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static GraphType buildCourseGraph(
        const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& prerequisites,
        const SizeType num_courses
    ) {
        GraphType graph(num_courses);

        for (const auto& prerequisite : prerequisites) {
            graph[prerequisite[1]].emplace_back(prerequisite[0]);
        }

        return graph;
    }

    static bool validateAcyclic(
        const GraphType& graph,
        const SizeType& course,
        std::vector<bool>& to_take,
        std::vector<bool>& taken
        
    ) {
        if (to_take[course]) {
            return false;
        }

        if (taken[course]) {
            return true;
        }

        to_take[course] = taken[course] = true;

        for (const auto& adj_course : graph[course]) {
            if (!validateAcyclic(graph, adj_course, to_take, taken)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        to_take[course] = false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

and here is LeetCode's depth first search solution in Java (with comments):

```
class Solution {
  public boolean canFinish(int numCourses, int[][] prerequisites) {

    // course -> list of next courses
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> courseDict = new HashMap<>();

    // build the graph first
    for (int[] relation : prerequisites) {
      // relation[0] depends on relation[1]
      if (courseDict.containsKey(relation[1])) {
        courseDict.get(relation[1]).add(relation[0]);
      } else {
        List<Integer> nextCourses = new LinkedList<>();
        nextCourses.add(relation[0]);
        courseDict.put(relation[1], nextCourses);
      }
    }

    boolean[] checked = new boolean[numCourses];
    boolean[] path = new boolean[numCourses];

    for (int currCourse = 0; currCourse < numCourses; ++currCourse) {
      if (this.isCyclic(currCourse, courseDict, checked, path))
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }


  /*
   * postorder DFS check that no cycle would be formed starting from currCourse
   */
  protected boolean isCyclic(
      Integer currCourse, HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> courseDict,
      boolean[] checked, boolean[] path) {

    // bottom cases
    if (checked[currCourse])
      // this node has been checked, no cycle would be formed with this node.
      return false;
    if (path[currCourse])
      // come across a previously visited node, i.e. detect the cycle
      return true;

    // no following courses, no loop.
    if (!courseDict.containsKey(currCourse))
      return false;

    // before backtracking, mark the node in the path
    path[currCourse] = true;

    boolean ret = false;
    // postorder DFS, to visit all its children first.
    for (Integer child : courseDict.get(currCourse)) {
      ret = this.isCyclic(child, courseDict, checked, path);
      if (ret)
        break;
    }

    // after the visits of children, we come back to process the node itself
    // remove the node from the path
    path[currCourse] = false;

    // Now that we've visited the nodes in the downstream,
    // we complete the check of this node.
    checked[currCourse] = true;
    return ret;
  }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/discuss/) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.